# Invalid value for Content Security Policy: Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy

I have been updating `manifest_version` of our chrome application and struggling a little bit with `content_security_policy`. They have stopped support for inline js and so many things. I wanted to relax this restriction by adding following line in my manifest

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

When I try to load unpacked extension from chrome, it gives me an error message 
`Invalid value for content_security_policy`.  Ironically, I have copied this line from [google's developer documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1) for chrome extension (plz see the section "Evaluated Javascript")

**Edit:** [Google thread](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7795) states that `unsafe-eval` is not supported in manifest version 2. How would I now use jquery and similar scripts that, I think, requires `unsafe-eval`?

Comment: You don't need unsafe-eval to use jQuery.

Comment: Update after 10 years: `unsafe-eval` works on manifest version 2, but it doesn't on manifest version 3

Answer (score 3):

`unsafe-eval` is mentioned in development, trunk and [beta](http://developer.chrome.com/beta/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) version of documentation, but it's missing in [stable](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) docs. You will probably have to wait for current beta to became stable. [Till then](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar) you can test your extension on [Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs).

Comment: Correct on both counts.The change was [merged back to Chrome 22](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=156949), which should be hitting the stable channel within a few weeks.